# Conection and send cookie between multiple AppService - Azure

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, backend, setcookie

I have 2 AppService, one for my django backend and another for my angular frontend. Each appService has its domain. On the login endpoint, the backend must generate and set a cookie with a jwt in the frontend context and domain to enable navigation.
From what I understand, since there are 2 app services with 2 different domains, the creation of the cookie in the backend corresponds to a different domain than the frontend and therefore this is rejected by the browser, rejecting the cookie. (Even configuring the httpOnly, Secure, Domain and path attribute in the backend).
Is it possible to configure that both appServices share the same domain, so that the cookie persists in the context of the frontEnd?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGEW2.png)

I tried setting the domain attribute in the backend setCookie to the frontend domain but the browser continues to reject it.

Comment: Hi @JulianGibelli, how you set the Domain attribute of the cookie to the shared domain in your Django code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure that both appServices share the same domain

***Yes, we can configure it by adding custom domain taken an (e.g., `backend.example.com` or `frontend.example.com`).***

[image]

[image]

- We need to verify ownership of the domain by adding DNS records provided by Azure to your domain registrar's DNS settings.
- Repeat the same process for the other App Service Angular frontend, adding the same custom domain.

**Django:**

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def login(request):
    # Perform login logic
    # Assuming jwt_token is the JWT token you want to set
    response = JsonResponse({'message': 'Login Successful'})
    response.set_cookie('jwt_token', 'your_jwt_token', domain='frontend.example.com')
    return response
```

**Angular:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  private apiUrl = 'https://backend.example.com';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(credentials: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/login/`, credentials, { withCredentials: true });
  }
}
```

Include the `withCredentials: true` option in your HTTP requests.

- Configure both the backend and frontend to share cookies and cross-origin requests.

Configure CORS to the Django Backend, In the settings Django backend App Service, you can find the CORS settings section. Add the domain `https://frontend.example.com` to the list of allowed origins

As per the above configuring `Headers-set_cookies` with both the applications the cookies persist in the context of the one domain only.

[image]